# Conditional probability with inequality

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

It is known that: $P(X > a) = 1 - P(X \leq a)$
Is there a rule for $P(X > a | Y > b)$ ? Maybe something similar to:

$P(X > a | Y > b) = 1- P(X < a | Y < b)$
(I am not sure, just a guess)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X > a | Y > b) = 1- P(X \le a | Y >b)$ is true since

\begin{align*}
&P(X > a | Y > b)+P(X \le a | Y >b)\\
=&\frac{P( X>a \& Y>b)}{P(Y>b)}+\frac{P( X\le a \& Y>b)}{P(Y>b)}\\
=&\frac{P(Y>b)}{P(Y>b)}\\
=&1
\end{align*}

Comment: The original equation should be a typo, where $P(X<a|Y<b)$ should be $P(X\le a | Y>b)$. Need @StackOMeow to confirm.

Comment: I hope it is a typo, but the OP stated something like "...just a guess..", so maybe it is not a typo. Let's wait and see.

Comment: It was just a guess (did not calculate) I guessed that if I do  1- then each term flips the inequality position so > becomes <

Answer (score 0):

$P(X > a | Y > b) = 1- P(X \leq a | Y > b)$

\begin{align}
&P(X > a | Y > b) = \frac{P(\{X>a\} \cap \{Y>b\})}{P(\{Y>b\})} 
= \frac {P(\{Y>b\})- P(\{X\leq a\} \cap \{Y>b\})}{P(\{Y>b\})} 
\\&= 1 - \frac{P(\{X\leq a\} \cap \{Y>b\})}{P(\{Y>b\}} 
= 1- P(X \leq a | Y > b) 
\end{align}